# select both bars in the same x position with layered barcharts

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I have the following visualization, which, if you paste to the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/edited), is a layered barchart. Right now, when I select a bar, I do not want to just select the bar itself but the bar(s) that are in the same x position.

The only solution I can think of has to use vega and explicitly reference the underlying dataset (since the `selection` signal is offset based, and not data based).

Might you know how this might be done in vega-lite?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "selection": {
    "select": {"type": "multi"}
  },
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"STAT_CAUSE_DESCR": "Arson", "count": 804, "is_overview": true},
      {"STAT_CAUSE_DESCR": "Arson", "count": 604, "is_overview": false},
      {"STAT_CAUSE_DESCR": "Campfire", "count": 231, "is_overview": true},
      {"STAT_CAUSE_DESCR": "Children", "count": 97, "is_overview": true},
      {"STAT_CAUSE_DESCR": "Children", "count": 50, "is_overview": false},
      {
        "STAT_CAUSE_DESCR": "Debris Burning",
        "count": 1175,
        "is_overview": true
      },
      {
        "STAT_CAUSE_DESCR": "Debris Burning",
        "count": 115,
        "is_overview": false
      },
      {"STAT_CAUSE_DESCR": "Equipment Use", "count": 301, "is_overview": true},
      {"STAT_CAUSE_DESCR": "Equipment Use", "count": 51, "is_overview": false},
      {
        "STAT_CAUSE_DESCR": "Missing/Undefined",
        "count": 233,
        "is_overview": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "STAT_CAUSE_DESCR", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "count", "type": "quantitative", "stack": null},
    "color": {
      "field": "is_overview",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {"range": ["#003E6B", "#9FB3C8"], "domain": [false, true]},
      "legend": null
    },
    "opacity": {"value": 0.5},
    "stroke": {"value": "#F0B429"},
    "strokeWidth": {
      "condition": [
        {
          "test": {
            "and": [{"selection": "select"}, "length(data(\"select_store\"))"]
          },
          "value": 3
        }
      ],
      "value": 0
    }
  },
  "config": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the encodings you want your selection to apply to within the selection definition. In your case, the selection specification would look like this:

```
  "selection": {
    "select": {"type": "multi", "encodings": ["x"]}
  },
```

View the result [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCixkY5PDw8VOUBAiQtOvdjDBIeAJ6FkVyKlZj9aqMiXxuAE0YlalgrAG1IAA9IAF0AXw1Y9VM-dDxMIw1TCnQxVmQQnFDMkxsAZQAVAEFygH0AYUqAVVKAURqAERbSuoAlZ0qAJ0UVVShfViU8KwAOAAZpUchGWBruKgGKRmQAdys8AbzE4ogyqtqG5rbO7r6cSEHhz0hxyasANnnF5dX1zZ2rABmOS0RxMJUgFWq9SarQ6XV6zjq6FQhABjAGTkWLymOAATABmACMXxWa2QGy2uxw+0OSTB1ghZ2hlzhN0RiEYYj8GJGY24ExxYAAnAB2Ek-cl-KlgGnIUH005Qi6w64Iu51DlcnlPbFWACss3FZIp-xwQLEILpYOM9NMkPOMKu8NuUHayHYA2WYAAQqwBkpAtQ1McTM9+a8cITCSK9Vb6UtSb9KXsDsgQ-LrSG7UzlU62Xc3R6vb7-YHg7bTLrI4TY1moN9jVLAcC07aM+D7cyVc7nC0AI6sRiEVDePBgRpaHXhwX42bE+uJyXJ6mp9snRlKx2stVQfuD4ej8eTrHT-XzhMSk3S82WkM220bh0s1UuyAAWWWsEDpEaSj8yDRJRkD8csKzDAUrAJfE4zBC9G2XGVU3TYpogSOkXHQAYAGtnHYTDQMgbxfACIIrHvKAoiMSA0W0EC7k7XNtz6RZ7EcZxuAGEickgdtIDsMjqK2LlnF1FiHCcO4B3QSZmFSRgqCeWA0ngHCcCUNwxF43wxA4siQ0E2jnAbJN-hgqBWIkqAlG4VBAm4syzHgHJLJsAZpOoSzwgAYlmWZ8RaN5vSeLyhQAMW9fE6mmGJFj8Gz0ECMIb2QUZZTiBydA8v8rHUsQxGKXjuEIdB4GYfiqOyXJLNmOg9V4pSBm4LCXMgSq8mcLzQtmb1pFxIUeLjMx9ia5AAHVGD8Fg9IfXw-2YAwwjrciHzwfJBWWsDpLosBQhscxdH0ZRnH2yxEigHQghYAAKFI0iugAdMxtAOmolI45BHoASk+mI6wgNd4zayz8TreJbWiBygasWYCrQjQwyUNEgyMeJYiAA):

[image]